# Smarty condition url not working

Tags: php, smarty

I used this code for checking if the url has a value and it is work but how can i check if the url not containing the value ??

```
 {if $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|strstr:'TEST'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Exclamation point at the beginning of your condition should do the trick

```
{if !$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|strstr:'TEST'}
```